# Perl's file test operator -f returns true for symbolic links

Tags: perl, shell, unix, find

I used to think that `-f` tested a file to see if it was a regular file, and not anything else. But Perl seems to be behaving differently. I looked up the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) entry , and it says:

```
-f  File is a plain file.
```

Suppose I have a directory having one file called `file1`, and 5 symbolic links `1 2 3 4 5`, each of which point to `file1`, like so:

```
-rw-r--r-- file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 -> file1
lrwxrwxrwx 2 -> file1
lrwxrwxrwx 3 -> file1
lrwxrwxrwx 4 -> file1
lrwxrwxrwx 5 -> file1
drwxr-xr-x ../
drwxr-xr-x ./
```

If I run find on this directory using `-type f` filter, it gives output as expected:

```
%  find . -type f
./file1
```

But when I run a perl script using -f operator, it gives following output:

```
%  ls | perl -e 'while(<>) { chomp; print "$_\n" if -f $_ }'
1
2
3
4
5
file1
```

When I add the test of `-l` too, it works as expected:

```
%  ls | perl -e 'while(<>) { chomp; print "$_\n" if -f $_ and not -l $_}'
file1
```

Are symbolic links considered plain files too? If so, Why? Is my usage of the file test incorrect?

Comment: Related: [`-x`](http://p3rl.org/-x) is a short-cut for the `stat` system call. If one wants to make a distinction for symlinks themselves, resort to [`lstat`](http://p3rl.org/File::stat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Quick solutions

```
$ ls | perl -lne 'print if stat && -f _'
1
2
3
4
5
file1

$ ls | perl -lne 'print if lstat && -f _'
file1
```

### Symbolic links and find

By default, GNU `find` never dereferences or follows symbolic links, but the [`find` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Symbolic-Links.html#Symbolic-Links) describes switches that change this policy.

> The options controlling the behaviour of find with respect to links are as follows :-
>
> `-P`
>   `find` does not dereference symbolic links at all. This is the default behaviour. This option must be specified before any of the file names on the command line.
>
> `-H`
>   `find` does not dereference symbolic links (except in the case of file names on the command line, which are dereferenced). If a symbolic link cannot be dereferenced, the information for the symbolic link itself is used. This option must be specified before any of the file names on the command line.
>
> `-L`
>   `find` dereferences symbolic links where possible, and where this is not possible it uses the properties of the symbolic link itself. This option must be specified before any of the file names on the command line. Use of this option also implies the same behaviour as the `-noleaf` option. If you later use the `-H` or `-P` options, this does not turn off `-noleaf`.
>
> `-follow`
>   This option forms part of the “expression” and must be specified after the file names, but it is otherwise equivalent to `-L`. The `-follow` option affects only those tests which appear after it on the command line. This option is deprecated. Where possible, you should use `-L` instead.

### Converting find commands to Perl

The standard distribution comes with a [`find2perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/x2p/find2perl.PL) utility that is compatible with `find` from older Unix systems.

```
$ find2perl . -type f | perl
./file1
```

We could instead ask for files that are either plain files themselves or links to plain files.

```
$ find2perl . -follow -type f | perl
./1
./2
./3
./4
./5
./file1
```

In the code `find2perl` generates, the default `wanted` sub passed to [`find` from the File::Find module](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/File/Find.pm#find) is

```
sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _
    && print("$name\n");
}
```

but with `-follow`, we get

```
sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = stat($_)) &&
    -f _
    && print("$name\n");
}
```

Notice that the only difference is whether `wanted` calls [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) or [`lstat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html), where the latter is documented as

> **`lstat EXPR`**
>   **`lstat`**
>
> Does the same thing as the [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) function (including setting the special `_` filehandle) but stats a symbolic link instead of the file the symbolic link points to. If symbolic links are unimplemented on your system, a normal [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) is done. For much more detailed information, please see the documentation for [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).
>
> If *EXPR* is omitted, stats `$_`.

As the sample outputs from `find2perl` shows, you can express your intent with the filetest operator but be precise about the semantics of symlinks with your choice of `stat` versus `lstat`.

### That funny `_` token

The `_` at the ends of the quick solutions above is the special filehandle that the [`lstat` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html) mentions. It holds a copy of the most recent result from `stat` or `lstat` as a way to avoid having to repeatedly make those expensive system calls. [Filetest operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) such as `-f`, `-r`, `-e`, and `-l` also fill this buffer:

> If any of the file tests (or either the `stat` or `lstat` operator) is given the special filehandle consisting of a solitary underline, then the stat structure of the previous file test (or `stat` operator) is used, saving a system call. (This doesn't work with `-t`, and you need to remember that `lstat` and `-l` leave values in the stat structure for the symbolic link, not the real file.) (Also, if the stat buffer was filled by an `lstat` call, `-T` and `-B` will reset it with the results of `stat _`). Example:
>
> ```
> print "Can do.\n" if -r $a || -w _ || -x _;
>
> stat($filename);
> print "Readable\n" if -r _;
> print "Writable\n" if -w _;
> print "Executable\n" if -x _;
> ```

Comment: I think the short version here is that if you filetest by name, the lookup will always follow symlinks, but that if you use `stat` or `lstat` plus a filetest on the `_` handle, you can control whether it's followed or not.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks for the subtle suggestion! Updated.

Comment: From Adrian's answer, I understood that all the magic/logic lies in the `stat` and `lstat` functions. But then I couldn't quite correlate the result from `find`, and `man find` was a little difficult to understand. Thanks very much for the doc link and the explanation.

Answer (score 17):

When you test a symlink, the test is carried out on the thing that the symlink points to unless you use the `-l` symlink test.

This parallels the `stat` and `lstat` Linux system-calls which behave similarly.  That is, if you `stat` a symlink, you'll get the result for the target of the symlink, whereas if you `lstat` the symlink, you'll get the result for the symlink itself.  This behaviour is intentional so that naïve programs don't have to care about symlinks, and symlinks will just work as intended.

You should find that if your symlink refers to a directory, the `-f` test is false and the `-d` test is true.

Comment: +1. [`perldoc stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html), [`perdoc lstat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lstat.html)

Answer (score 3):

By default all the file test operators (apart from `-l`) use `stat()` to test, which means they are transparent to symlinks. `-f` returns true on a regular file, or a symlink to a regular file.

In order to use `lstat()` instead, you should first `lstat` then use the file tests on the special `_` filehandle, which stores the results from the most recent `stat` or `lstat` operation.

```
perl -e 'while(<>) { chomp; print "$_\n" if lstat $_ && -f _ }'
```